# can we Call webservice hoted in .net 4.0 from website hoted in 2.0?

Tags: web-services, web-config

I have a website say www.xyz.com which hosted in .net 2.0
Also  i have virtual directory www.xyz.com/demo which is hosted in .net 4.0

Now when i call webservice hosted inside virtual directory (www.xyz.com/demo)
from main website (www.xyz.com)

it shows
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory'.

I've some thing like this in main website config file

Any suggestion

**Many Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of web services is that you don't need to know about the language or platform they are implemented in. So yes, you can consume a .NET 4.0 web service with .NET 2.0, PHP, whatever, provided that the web service actually *works*.

Comment: I don't have a solution, your question was: Can I use web service (.NET 4) from .NET 2 - the answer ist "yes". Maybe you didn't include the required assemblies? Maybe your service is not a real web service? Are your sure you're talking about web *services* and not a web *site*? Sounds to me that you simply have to web sites, on e written with ASP.NET 2.0 and one with ASP.NET 4.0 (which is something different than a web *service*!). You need to activate .NET 4 for the web folders in IIS.